# Interpolating raster corridors in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, mosaic

I have a set of 24 raster (2.5 x 2.5 km, tif) that displays vegetation (from las). However, there is a 10 m symmetric grid of unprocessed lines between the tiles.

Any way to interpolate these?

I have looked into ArcMap Focal Statistics tool, but I don't think this is a solution. I do want to "copy-paste" 5 m och each edge, move 5 m and finally mosaic these.

Ideas?

Rectify?

The elevation isolines are in shp and a later problem - snap?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the tiles into one big raster, then create a new raster using zonal statistics to interpolate every point from the big tiled raster. This will interpolate the gap points, but also the rest of the points too.

To only use the gap points you could insert only the "gap" locations from this new raster back into the old raster. If the "gaps" are coded a particular way (say as null or a negative value), this final step could be accomplished using the Con tool.